# "Right" way to tell relatively shifted div that the original place no longer occupied

Tags: html, css

As long as I see when I position an element (for example flash player) relatively to previously placed image as in the example

```
style="display: block; width:216px;height:164px; position: relative; top: -306px; left: 63px"
```

the place that it intended to use before is looked occupied, i.e. next element will be shown AFTER that place. But I need to tell the rendered that I no longer need this place and that the next element can be rendered as if the relatively placed element didn't appear at all.

The only solution I found is to wrap the content in an external div with with the dimensions of the main image and "overflow: hidden"

Is there a better (or "right" as in the title) way to do the same?

Answer (score 3):

You use absolute positioning instead of relative positionning to get the element out of the flow.

If you still want to specify the coordinates relative to a position in the document, you put another element around it. By setting relative positioning (but no offset) on the surrounding element you turn it into a layer, so that the absolutely positioned element uses that as origin instead of the page.

Example:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
   <div style="position:absolute;top:-306px;left:63px;">content...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> A relatively positioned box keeps its
>   normal flow size, including line
>   breaks and the space originally
>   reserved for it.

[Relative positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#relative-positioning)

One way is to place the child element as absolutely positioned inside another container with position set.